# Is there something I need to do to QM files to make them seen by my QT Application?

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

I'm writing a PacMan classic arcade game clone in QT / C++ and trying to learn Internationalization by trying to put it into the game for the limited # of strings in the game(such as "Ready" and such) - Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to install a translation.  I don't know if it's succeeding or failing at an initial installation of translation file because it's English so no translation - but I have 2 mechanisms to change the language - a menu and a combo box - Both call installTranslator() which is a pubic function on my Controller class PacManController.  Inside there, there's an if & body that if there is a translator created, it removes it from the Application.  After that, it loads the file corresponding to the language name selected.  I've verified with a QFile::exists outputting with qDebug() that the exact file path I'm using exists.  However, it skips over the body of the if statement testing the load for true or false (so it returns false presumably).  Do I need to do something special to get the load to work?  I only included 2 languages in my resources(qrc) file for now (English and Nederlands(dutch) - because of the languages I translated, those files didn't have any weird characters in the names).  Here is the code for my installTranslator method in the Controller class:

```
void PacManController::installTranslator(const QString &sLanguage)
{
    bool bExists = QFile::exists(":/languages/" + sLanguage);
    qDebug() << "The file " << (bExists ? "exists!" : "does not exist.");

    if(mPtrTranslator != nullptr)
        getApplication().removeTranslator(mPtrTranslator);

    if(getTranslator().load(":/languages/" + sLanguage))
        {
        getApplication().installTranslator(&getTranslator());

        getApplication().getMainWindow().retranslateUI();
        }
}
```

I didn't know if maybe I needed to do something more with lUpdate/lRelease or in the PRO file to get this to work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for sarcasm, but, *"(so it returns false presumably)"*, if only there was a way to find out instead of presuming... Anyway, I'd look into `getTranslator().load()` and see what happens in there, when you give it a path to resource file.

Comment: I pass the exact same path that I pass previously to the QFile::exists() method.  And that returns that the file exists.  All the examples I've ever seen say just to put the language file - leave off ".qm" but even with .qm it doesn't break inside the 'if' statement body - it skips it entirely so yes presumably it is returning false :-P  If I knew what might cause it to return false, I wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: getTranslator just returns the QTranslator but dereferenced so a reference and not a pointer and load executes QTranslator::load().  The documentation is telling me nothing useful.

Comment: Try loading it from normal file (use absolute path, this is for debugging purposes). Pethaps the .qm file is invalid somehow (like, wrong encoding used, or just broken file).